# Error copying images from camera using Nautilus

Tags: 13.04, usb-drive, camera

Since I upgraded t 13.04 I can no longer copy images from a flash card located in my Canon camera.

I can connect to the camera using USB, I can browse and view images, however I am unable to copy any images to my PC.

The error message: Operation not supported by backend

The strange thing is that I can copy folders, just not contents...

Any ideas?

Ubuntu 13.04 64bit
Kernel: 3.9.7-030907-generic

Thanks

Additional:
I do not think the camera is mounting properly. I wonder if it has something to do with gphoto2?

In order to mount it correctly in an application I have to first unmount the camera from from nautilus.

I think the issue lies with the mounting of the camera....?

```
pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~$ ls -a /media
.  ..  apt  .directory  MyAndroid  pst007x
pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~$
```

Location in Nautilus is shown as:  gphoto2://[usb:002,012]/

Comment: What sort of camera are you using? and what software are you trying to down load the images in to? I use Shotwell which seems to work flawlessly with my Nikon D90 and my iPhone

Comment: Shotwell will import to whatever folder you have set in the prefs.  If that isn't working for you, please file a ticket.

Comment: I have always just dragged the DCIM folder from my camera to the desktop. I do not like the way shotwell organises my photos into date. I end up with loads of folders containing a single image. Thanks

Comment: You get The error message: Operation not supported by backend is when you try to move or copy/paste files into a target folder where you don't have write permission, or if the target file system is mounted as read-only.

Comment: No not a shotwell issue. I have full permissions for media* and home folders. Copying from Camera flash to desktop. Thanks

Comment: Are you able to copy these files using command line with `cp -r /media/yourcamera /home/user/destination` replacing the paths to directories with your own? Note that this will copy all files and directories within /media/yourcamera to the destination.

Comment: How do I find the camera mount point, it does not appear in the media folder. The location appears to be gphoto2://[usb:002,012]/

Comment: The strange thing is that I can copy folders, just not contents...

Comment: You don't see it if you run `ls -a /media`? Can you get the location in nautilus? Pressing ctrl+L in nautilus should toggle the location view as a path.

Comment: This is the path shown: gphoto2://[usb:002,012]/

Comment: pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~$ ls -a /media                           
.  ..  apt  .directory  MyAndroid  pst007x

Comment: Run `sudo blkid`. Does it show your device as TYPE="ntfs"?

See if you can manually mount the device using the instructions here. Note the instructions for ntfs file systems if that is the case. [Mount/USB
 - Manually Mounting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB#Manually_Mounting) You may need to unmount the device before manually mounting it. [Unmounting Explained](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB#Unmounting_Explained)

Comment: This also happens with the Xperia Z1 phone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this is broken in all recent Gnome releases.

- Debian: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=715436
- Fedora 19: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=984913
- Arch Linux: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=165497

The Arch thread has several workarounds, my favorite is using "gphoto2 -P":

1. Connect camera
2. Eject camera via Nautilus
3. Open a terminal, cd to the directory you want your photos to be placed, run "gphoto2 -P". It will download all the images to the current directory.

If you don't have gphoto2 installed: sudo apt-get install gphoto2